# Linux redirection pipe

Tags: linux, pipe, io

I was testing out a kind of backwards indirection and came across this. I'm not specifying the desired behavior as there is none - I just want to understand the results - a sym link to an (unnamed?) pipe? In a few steps, what is going on?

```
pehlic@ely:~/src/bash/sandbox/bash$ ls -al >(cat)
l-wx------ 1 pehlic pehlic 64 Jan 13 23:39 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[26718]
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually doing an `ls -al` and passing that into `cat`, it's doing a process substitution on `cat` and presenting that as a file to `ls -al` which will then do a listing on the file.

So the process substitution creates a pipe connecting a file-object and `stdin` of the "inner" program, `cat` here and presents a file to the "outer" program.  Then you do an `ls` on that, and see that it has offered the "file" `/dev/fd/63`.

Comment: Right, process substitution - thx.